# Cannot Alert formdata onSubmit()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to alert my captured formdata from a dynamically generated form.

```
<body>
    <div id="main1">
        <input type="button" onclick="addSelectBox ()" name="clickme" value="+" />
        <input type="button" onclick="removeSelect();" value="-" />
        <input type="button" onclick="xmlData();" value="XML" />
    </div>
    <form id="autoPopulation_form" method='post'>
        <div id="main"></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

However it fails with this error on JSFiddle:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x3e29f50>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x3f33f50>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x3e29f50>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x3f33c10>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3542N/5/)

Can anybody help me out, I am trying to view all of my formdata

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error. It should be `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementByid`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('autoPopulation_form').onsubmit = function () {
        var frmData = new FormData(this);
        alert(frmData);
        // return false; // uncomment this if you don't want the form to actually be submitted.
    };
};
```

**Edit**:
The "onSubmit" should also be changed to "onsubmit", apparently.

Comment: isn't it the same..??

Comment: `id` should start with a capital I. :)

Comment: You're right, that's not the only issue. See my edit.

Comment: @rahul888 you can ignore the jsFIddle erorr, open your browser console and see the js errors there.  The fiddle error is because jsfiddle accepts only ajax requests

Comment: @vdwijngaert , spokey : I tried everything , but still can't figure how to use this data in my other functions . I want all the individual inputs and text boxes in separate variables.